# How to get ActionResult StatusCode in ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, actionresult

I have an API whose return type is `ActionResult`:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<ActionResult> MyFunction(MyFunctionInput input) 
{
    if (input.Id == null) 
    {
        retrun BadRequest("Id must exist");
    }

    // Do some stuff

    return Ok();
}
```

I am calling this function from another API in same class and storing the result in a variable. But when ever I am trying to get the `StatusCode` from the result, it says `ActionResult` does not contain a definition for `StatusCode` like this

```
var response = await MyFunction(attInput);

if (response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.NotFound || 
    response.StatusCode == System.Net.HttpStatusCode.BadRequest)
{
    //To Do
}
```

I googled it but almost everyone said to convert the result to `OkObjectResult`.

What should I do now?

Comment: Well - did you look at the [official MS documentation for `ActionResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.actionresult?view=aspnetcore-6.0)  ?? It clearly shows - that information just isn't present. Do you really need that? You need to check what kind of result you got - an `OkObjectResult` probably indicates success (http 200) - while any exception most likely indicates an error.......

Comment: In other words: the HTTP status code is ***NOT*** on the `ActionResult` - but how are you calling your Web API? Most likely with a `HttpClient` (or a library like RestSharp's `RestClient`) - **that's** where you will find the HTTP status code of your **call**, once the call is completed - on the client calling the API - not on the API's response object....

Comment: I updated `UploadTruckEquipmentAttachments` to `MyFunction`. It do some operation like storing files in database.. The function always returns either Success status or Error status..

Answer (score 2):

When looking at the source code of [`ActionResult<T>`](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/v6.0.11/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/ActionResultOfT.cs), we could see this:

```cs
public sealed class ActionResult<TValue> : IConvertToActionResult
```

and

```cs
IActionResult IConvertToActionResult.Convert()
{
    if (Result != null)
    {
        return Result;
    }

    int statusCode;
    if (Value is ProblemDetails problemDetails && problemDetails.Status != null)
    {
        statusCode = problemDetails.Status.Value;
    }
    else
    {
        statusCode = DefaultStatusCode;
    }

    return new ObjectResult(Value)
    {
        DeclaredType = typeof(TValue),
        StatusCode = statusCode
    };
}
```

So it's there, but you need some code to get it:

```cs
private static int? GetStatusCode<T>(ActionResult<T?> actionResult)
{
    IConvertToActionResult convertToActionResult = actionResult; // ActionResult implicit implements IConvertToActionResult
    var actionResultWithStatusCode = convertToActionResult.Convert() as IStatusCodeActionResult;
    return actionResultWithStatusCode?.StatusCode;
}
```

Example usage:

```cs
ActionResult<MyResponse> actionResult = await controller.Get(request);
var statuscode = GetStatusCode(actionResult);
```

Please note, this seem to be implemented in .NET 6

Answer (score 0):

Julian's answer is quite helpful in my case. Based from the sample code provided by Julian, what I did is I explicitly casted the response to IStatusCodeActionResult for me to gain access to the StatusCode property. I was able to cast the response because the method signature of my controller method is of type Task and IStatusCodeActionResult interface depends on IActionResult.

ie:

```
var response = await controller.GetJob(_id);
// Should be 200 or 404
int? statusCode = ((IStatusCodeActionResult)response).StatusCode;
```

Method Signature:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> GetJob(Guid id) { ... }
```

Answer (score -1):

Firstly,as you said,ActionResult does not contain a definition for StatusCode.If you want to get StatusCode with `response.StatusCode`,you can try to use HttpClient as `Zanyar J.Ahmed` shown.If you want to get StatusCode with `await MyFunction(attInput);`,you can try to set statuscode with Session in `MyFunction`.

Startup.cs:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();

        services.AddSession(options =>
        {
            options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10);
            options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
            options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
        });

       ...
    }

    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IWebHostEnvironment env)
    {
        ...
        app.UseAuthentication();
        app.UseAuthorization();

        app.UseSession();

        ...
    }
```

api:

```
[HttpPost("UploadFiles")]
public async Task<ActionResult> MyFunction(MyFunctionInput input) 
{
    if (input.Id == null) 
    {
        HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("StatusCode", 400);
        retrun BadRequest("Id must exist");
    }

    // Do some stuff
    if (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("StatusCode") == null)
            {
                HttpContext.Session.SetInt32("StatusCode", 200);
            }
    return Ok();
}
```

get status code:

```
var response = await MyFunction(attInput);

if (HttpContext.Session.GetInt32("StatusCode")=400)
{
    //To Do
}
```

Answer (score -2):

> Your question need more explain !!! How to call ? you use HttpClient
> ? or call by Ajax ? Please edit your question by answer me questions.

### Generally explain how to get states code in below

If you want request anther api in backend use [HttpClient](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient?view=net-6.0)

```
// TODO: make request
var response = await client.GetAsync(url);

// get status code 
if(response.StatusCode == StatusCode.Ok) // when your endpoint success state
{
    //TODO: write code here 
}
```

[Make HTTP requests using IHttpClientFactory in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/http-requests?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Comment: I am one function from another function in same class..